# Eclipse: Combine EE Version and Developer version

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, version

I have two versions of Eclipse (EE: when I program on Web platform and Developer version: normal version). I see that switching between this is not convenient.

My question is: Can I copy all plugins from EE version to Java Developer version, so that I can use components of EE in Java Developer version.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your direct question is: no, you cannot copy all of your EE plugins to your Java developer edition.

However, this is probably not really what you want to ask.  Mostly, the Java edition is a subset of the EE edition.  See the comparison here:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

Unless you require Window builder, or Maven integration, then you can use your EE edition for your plain Java development.

Otherwise, you can easily install any missing feature from the Eclipse update sites.  Go to Help -> Install new software and select "Indigo" (I am assuming you are working with Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).  And here you can choose any feature you want to install.

The important thing to realize is that the packages available are just convenient groupings of features.  There is nothing stopping you from installing (for example) all of Java EE in the Java developer edition.  Everything is available from the Indigo update site.

Comment: Oh. thanks :) I ask this because before I work on Eclipse EE, I work on normal version and many addtional plugins I have installed (but I cannot know what file name in plugin folder, so copy all maybe the solution)

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse 3.7, an alternative to the method suggested by [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755996/796559) is to use the Import Wizard "Install" -> "From Existing Installation". Here you can browse to the rot directory of the Java EE Edition and install all the features from that installation in the running Java Developer installation.

Comment: Good point.  Forgot about this.  It's probably the easiest way for this particular question.